PyQt6 - Elements with QVBoxLayout not scaling well after expanding the window
I have the following method which establishes a QVBoxLayout with several configuration widgets:
def ConfigureNewGraph(self):
        confWnd = QWidget()
        confWndLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        confWnd.setLayout(confWndLayout)

        xAxisLabel = QLineEdit()
        xAxisRange = QLineEdit()
        yAxisLabel = QLineEdit()
        yAxisRange = QLineEdit()
        graphTitle = QLineEdit()
        
        #Group box as selector for the input type: via file or via port. 
        dataStreamBox = QGroupBox("Input type")
        serialPortCheck = QCheckBox("Serial port")
        textFileCheck = QCheckBox("File")
        dataStreamLayout = QFormLayout()
        dataStreamLayout.addWidget(serialPortCheck)
        dataStreamLayout.addWidget(textFileCheck)
        dataStreamBox.setLayout(dataStreamLayout)
        confWndLayout.addWidget(dataStreamBox)
        
        #Serial port input handler
        serialConfig = SerialConfig() 
        dataStreamLayout.addWidget(serialConfig.serialBox)
         
        #File input handler
        fileConfig = FileConfig()
        dataStreamLayout.addWidget(fileConfig.fileBox)
        
        #Widget to configure plot info
        plotInfoBox = QGroupBox("Plot information")
        plotInfoLayout = QFormLayout()
        plotInfoLayout.addRow("Plot title: ",graphTitle)
        plotInfoLayout.addRow("x axis label: ",xAxisLabel)
        plotInfoLayout.addRow("x axis range:",xAxisRange)
        plotInfoLayout.addRow("y axis label: ",yAxisLabel)
        plotInfoLayout.addRow("y axis range:",yAxisRange)
        plotInfoBox.setLayout(plotInfoLayout)
        
        confWndLayout.addWidget(plotInfoBox)
        
        serialPortCheck.toggled.connect(lambda checked: serialConfig.serialBox.setVisible(checked))#Shows the portBox 
        serialConfig.connectButton.clicked.connect(lambda: sc.ConnectToPort(serialConfig.baudRateInput.text(),serialConfig.portInput.text(),serialConfig.dataSizeInput.text(),serialConfig.connectionState))
        
        textFileCheck.toggled.connect(lambda checked: fileConfig.fileBox.setVisible(checked))#Shows the fileBox
        
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(confWnd)

And here is the class that implements the behavior for the SerialPort configuration:
class SerialConfig():
    def __init__(self):
        #Serial port configuration, can be expanded
        self.serialBox = QGroupBox()
        self.serialBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.portInput = QLineEdit()
        self.baudRateInput = QLineEdit()
        self.dataSizeInput = QLineEdit()
        self.connectionStateLabel = QLabel("Connection status")
            
        #self.connectionStateWidget
        self.connectionState = QTextEdit()
        self.connectionState.setReadOnly(True)
        self.connectionState.setFixedSize(350,80)
        
        self.serialInfoWidget = QWidget()
        self.serialInfoLayout = QFormLayout()
        self.serialInfoWidget.setLayout(self.serialInfoLayout)
        self.serialInfoLayout.addRow("Port:",self.portInput)
        self.serialInfoLayout.addRow("Baud rate:",self.baudRateInput)
        self.serialInfoLayout.addRow("Size of data package (in bytes):",self.dataSizeInput)
        
        
        self.connectButton = QPushButton("Connect")
        

        #Layout order
        self.serialBoxLayout.addWidget(self.serialInfoWidget)
        self.serialBoxLayout.addWidget(self.connectButton)
        self.serialBoxLayout.addWidget(self.connectionStateLabel)
        self.serialBoxLayout.addWidget(self.connectionState)
        
        
        self.serialBox.setLayout(self.serialBoxLayout)
        self.serialBox.setVisible(False)


This is how it looks on the default size  (QSize(800,600)) after running the application:

And this is how it looks like after maxing the window:

Is there any way to keep the distances within widgets when I resize my window?
I'm quite new to PyQt so any other comment is welcome. Thank you!

I suppose that by "keep the distances" you're referring to the vertical alignment of the left widgets. If that's the case, then just add confWndLayout.addStretch() at the end of ConfigureNewGraph (possibly right before than self.mainLayout.addWidget(confWnd), but it actually doesn't change the result). Note that you should avoid: 1. dummy classes (simple python objects, no inheritance) especially when using Qt, connecting signals and with non persistent references (SerialConfig should probably inherit from QGroupBox and get rid of self.serialBox); 2. capitalized names for functions.

Appreciate the answer. That worked!
Do you mind elaborating more on "connecting signals and with non persistent references"?

The serialConfig reference to the instance is just a local variable within ConfigureNewGraph. This means that that instance may be potentially garbage collected as soon as the function returns, taking away its members too. In this specific case it doesn't happen because: 1. the lambda creates a closure; 2. the widgets wouldn't be destroyed anyway since they've been reparented by Qt. Still, creating such an instance without any persistent reference is generally unsafe and discouraged; for instance, if instead of using a lambda you directly connected the toggled signal to a function of »

» SerialConfig that would then call self.serialBox.setVisible() with the signal argument, and supposing that the other lambda that uses serialConfig doesn't exist, then serialConfig would go out of scope when the function returns, therefore deleting the instance completely, disconnecting the signal in the meantime. See this simple example that clearly demonstrates what written above. Since you don't seem to actually use SerialConfig for anything else than "contain" references to widgets (including an actual widget »

» container for them, the group box), it makes little sense to use a basic class and an attribute for the real container. Instead, as said before, make it the actual container by inheriting from QGroupBox, remove self.serialBox, set the layout on self, and then directly add its serialConfig instance to the main layout. The only safe alternative is to make the reference persistent: either make an instance attribute (self.serialConfig), but only as long as it will never be overwritten, or use a container such a list and make that an instance attribute.
